# Area in between two concentric circles

Tags: circles, area

Area in between two concentric circles.

I am working on a problem and a bit stuck.

The problem is that we have two concentric circles, with the area inclosed by the inner circle equal to $7000\pi$ square meters . We are then given that the ratio of the circumference of the outer to the inner circle is equal to $8:7$ .

I realize that in order to solve this we need to understand the formulas for the area of a circle and the circumference of a circle.

Thus, we recognize that $C = 2\pi r$ and $A = \pi r^2$

We then conclude that $7000\pi = \pi r^2$ and find $r = \sqrt{7000}$

Now that we have this value, we need to find it in terms of the ratio $8:7$ in order to find the radius of the larger circle so that we can calculate its area and subtract that of the smaller circle. This is where I am stuck however, how do we convert the radius $\sqrt{7000}$ in to the appropriate ratio?

Do we just simply divide by seven and then multiply this value by eight?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you just multiply the radius by $\frac 87$.

Comment: @RossMillikan Thanks!

Comment: If the linear measure is in ratio $8:7$ then the area measure is in ratio $64:49$ ($8^2:7^2$).  Which means that the ratio of the area between them to the area of the smaller circle is $15:49$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$7C_{outer}=8C_{inner}$$

$$7(2\pi r_{outer})=8(2\pi r_{inner})$$

$$14\pi r_{outer}=16\pi r_{inner}$$

$$r_{outer}=\frac{8}{7} \ r_{inner}$$

$$r_{outer}=\frac{8}{7}\sqrt{7000}$$

Comment: Your first equation is incorrect .  It should be $8C_{inner}=7C_{outer}$.  This flows all the way through.  The outer radius should be larger than the inner radius, while you have it $\frac 78$ the size.

Comment: @RossMillikan Sorry about that. I realized once I read it over. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to find the area between those two circles , use the hint given below :

$ \frac {Area_{outer}}{Area_ {inner}} =\frac{ R²_{1}} {R²_{2}}. \,$

$\frac{Area_{outer}} {Area_ {inner}} =\frac{ 64}{49}. $

$\frac{(Area_{outer} - Area_ {inner})} { Area_{inner}} = \frac{15} {49}.  $

${Area_{outer} - Area_ {inner}} = Area_{remaining} $

$ =\frac {15}{49}× Area_{ inner} = \frac{15}{49} × 7000π = \frac{15000π}{7} sq. unit$

Hope it helps.

Comment: @Ethan  was that helpful ??